# Modal Window with HTML5 and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following a tutorial found [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) and I can't seem to get it to show up. I am using a bootstrap enabled website so I am not sure if that is the problem. I've been at it for two hours and can't seem to get anywhere. My button that I want users to click on in order to bring up the popup looks like this: `<a href="#openModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Contact Me</a>` The framework for the popup looks like this:

```
<div id="openModal" class="contactus">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS document looks like:

```
.contactus {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}

.contactus:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.contactus > div {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

I have JavaScript enabled on my browser it if you click on it, you can't scroll up on the page unless you press "Esc" so I think it's puling up, you just can't see it. I was thinking it had something to do with `z-index: 99999;` but I don't know what that does exactly.

Any ideas??

Comment: try to create a fiddle

Comment: It seems to work on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jXc5j/

Comment: The .contactus div has an opacity:0. Are you removing this dynamically?

Comment: The `z-index` is probably not the problem. The [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) controls what order elements are stacked in on the z-axis. If you imagine them as scraps of paper, it controls what order they are stacked on top of one another, the higher the value is, the higher the element goes in the stack. Using a very high number like `99999` is meant to ensure that the popup appears above everything else on the page.

Comment: have you tried using the bootstrap modal? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals or for 2.3.2 http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. If someone can, please check out [this](https://airxnetworks.com#contact) The first button should cause the example bootstrap modal to come up but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong??